# White text slightly difficult to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The white text at the top of the page (username, log out,meta, about, faq) are a little hard to read against the background. The tags are also hard to read. The grey background might need to be a bit darker for more contrast. The special badges, like the ones given for 100 posts in a given tag, are ok as the background for those are dark enough and provide good contrast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have bolded the text on the top. please let me know if you're still having problem reading the text.

Comment: That definitely looks better!

Comment: Overall can we have some more contrast to improve readability? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I agree. You have to realize that Jin designs on a Mac, where every font looks bold.. :)

Probably we should bold that top line to make it more readable.

Comment: Heh.  Jin probably also has a properly calibrated monitor, unlike most of the population.  The grey and white isn't too bad, but the blue and white are almost unreadable on my (less-than-new) secondary monitor.